# Getting the first character in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, switch-statement, conditional-statements

I am creating a crystal report where the receipt number is written as V0000001 or N0000001. I want to get the first character because that is what differentiates these receipt numbers. There is label that says VAT Or No for receipt  number V0000001, and a label that says NON VAT Or No. for N0000001.

Basically like this.

case V: VAT Or No:. V0000001

case N: NON-VAT Or No:. N0000001

I think that switch statement would be best, but I don't know how to write it.

The main question is, how would I change the label depending on the first character of the receipt number?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write something like this:

```
If Left ("V0000001", 1)='V'
then "VAT OR NO"
Else If Left ("N000001", 1)='N'
Then "NON-VAT OR No"
```

Comment: Thanks. I was able to make my own, I incorporated your's with mine and here's how it went. `stringvar receipt_no := {cash_print_official_rcpt.receipt_no};

If Left (receipt_no, 1)='V'
then "VAT OR NO"
Else If Left (receipt_no, 1)='N'
Then "NON-VAT OR No"`